# create index for mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection

```
{
  id: String,
  country: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  ...
}
```

What is the right indices for the collection using this aggregate?

```
.aggregate([
  { $match: { country: "US" } },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { id: '$id' },
      totalPrice: { $first: '$totalPrice' },
    },
  },
])
```

I have these indices on the schema

```
schema.index({ country: 1 });
schema.index({ createdAt: 1 });
schema.index({ country: 1, id: 1, createdAt: 1 });
```

But I think something is not healty

Comment: a composite index over `{ country: 1, createdAt: -1 }` shall help you with the query that you've shared